# Why does my pool pump have bubbles when on high?

Tags: pool

I am working on a 24' round 52" pool with a 1.5hp, 2 speed motor and a 26" sand filter, with 1.5 inch flex pipes, one 12 feet long to the filter and another 12 feet to the return.

When I run on low, no bubbles in the basket attached to the pump or the return.

When I run on high, it seems like it sucks in bubbles through the basket attached to the pump, I can see them and a bunch of super small ones come out of the return.

I've put in a new o-ring with lube and tightened it as much as I can and on high the bubbles still come in.

Is there anything else I can try?

Pump is a waterway SD 15-2n11m.  To answer a comment, it is a permanent install

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How sure are you that the air is being sucked in through the skimmer? Can you see the water level drop low enough that air could be sucked in there? I'd be concerned that you have a small leak in the pipes between the skimmer and the pump and it's sucking air in there...

Comment: Some more info on the pool would be helpful, a 52” is normally a permanent instal, but it sounds like a temp pool because of the flex. Is your skimmer a through the wall mount or bracket over the side. There are ways to reduce a world pool suction that puts air into the pump and can deprive some. But more information is needed including if through wall the width (in some cases 3 1/2” holes below the flapper float can solve an undersized skimmer issue sucking air but more info is needed.

Comment: thanks @brhans, I'm sorry, I meant the basket that's attached to the pump, that's where the bubbles are coming in.  The water doesn't drop enough in the skimmer basket to suck air in when it's turned on high.

Comment: are you sure the lid to the basket on the pump is tight?  check the "o" ring on the lid.

Comment: Yes, I have a new, tight o-ring, with lube on it, and it still does it.  Thanks @JACK.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate valves for the skimmer and drain, reduce the skimmer flow and increase the drain flow. You're operating your skimmer at a higher suction rate than it can handle and therefore sucking some air. Is the pool full? You might have to increase the water level of the skimmer. 
If you just have a skimmer and it's always full, then check the lid over the basket on the pump to make sure it tight and that the "o"ring is good. Also check your pump inlet connection for tightness.

Comment: Jack I would agree with some pools but with flex this may only have a side skimmer and probably no bottom drain, prior to the oil shortage and the big spike in the cost to heat a pool we installed quite a few, round pools normally did not have a bottom drain in our area if the bottom was lower or permanent. We built many zonalight cement bottom pools with liners back then to get around the temp permanent tax issues not the electrical requirements, that’s why I asked the additional questions. A skimmer bottom drain should be obvious though and a good point.

Comment: Correct @EdBeal, it only has a side skimmer and no bottom drain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the water flow on high speed is too much for that skimmer and air is sucked into the water flow. Apparently a higher capacity skimmer is required, or run motor at low speed. Or add a second inlet ,skimmer or bottom.

Comment: To me it is set up. I can make a 5 hp pump work but if the skimmer is set at the wrong height there are adjustments that can be made.

Comment: Thank you both, I've corrected my question to better reflect my situation.  The air doesn't come into the skimmer, but the basket attached to the pump.